# Structure & Design of FadeItems in a menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

**HTML:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navigation_desktop">

    <div class="button_desktop_01">1.0 Main Menu
        <div class="FadeItem_01">
            <ul>
                <li>1.1 Sub Menu </li>
                <li class="button_desktop_02">1.2 Sub Menu
                    <div class="FadeItem_02">
                        <ul>
                            <li>1.2.1 Sub Menu</li>
                            <li>1.2.2 Sub Menu</li>
                        </ul> 
                    </div>
                </li> 
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="button_desktop_01">2.0 Main Menu
        <div class="FadeItem_01">
            <ul>
                <li class="button_desktop_02">2.1 Sub Menu
                    <div class="FadeItem_02">
                        <ul>
                            <li>2.1.1 Sub Menu</li>
                            <li>2.1.2 Sub Menu</li>
                            <li>2.1.3 Sub Menu</li>
                        </ul> 
                    </div>
                </li> 
                <li>2.2 Sub Menu </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.button_desktop_01{
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 padding-left: 1%;
 padding-right: 1%;
 cursor: pointer;
 }

 .button_desktop_02 {
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 padding-left: 1%;
 padding-right: 1%;
 cursor: pointer;
 }

.FadeItem_01, .FadeItem_02 {
display: none
}

.FadeItem_02 {
position: absolute;
left: 100%;
top: 0;
width: 130px;
}

ul {
margin: 0;
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button_desktop_01, .button_desktop_02").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).children(".FadeItem_01, .FadeItem_02").fadeIn(500);
  });
  $(".button_desktop_01, .button_desktop_02").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).children(".FadeItem_01, .FadeItem_02").fadeOut(500);
  });
});
```

The code above **FadeIn/Out** some menus. The items which are under the `<div class="FadeItem_02">` appear right next to the items under the `<div class="FadeItem_01">`. All this works perfectly so far.

I want to achieve now that the items which are under the `<div class="FadeItem_02">` exactly match with the size of the `button_desktop_01` *(1.0 Main Menu)* or `button_desktop_02` *(2.0 Main Menu)* .

Right now they appear very close to the `<div class="FadeItem_01">` which does not really look professional.

What do I have to change in my CSS to achieve this?

You can also find the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/gng5dcLc/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/gng5dcLc/6/

```
.FadeItem_02 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 110%;
  top: 0;
  width: 130px;
}
```

Since you are using `left` in  `CSS`, thats why I updated the `left` to *110%** to **100%**

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi Shiladitya, thanks for you answer. It looks good. By the way, is it good to use "left" in CSS or do you know a better way to do it?

Comment: @Michi... If you specify position as `absolute` then you need to specify `left` & `top`, so you can go with the solution whatever you have. Try out `slideDown` & ` slideUp` instead of `fadeIn` &  `fadeOut`. Also check this out https://jsfiddle.net/gng5dcLc/7/.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. The slideup/slidedown looks nice too.

Answer (score 0):

you can add css

```
.FadeItem_02 ul {
    padding-left: 12%; /* whatever style you want*/
}
```

check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/gng5dcLc/5/)