# Hover effect in jQuery slideUp/Down menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

**HTML:**

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="navigation_desktop">

            <div class="button_desktop_01">1.0 Main Menu
                <div class="SlideItem_01">
                    <div>1.1 Sub Menu</div>
                    <div class="button_desktop_02">1.2 Sub Menu
                        <div class="SlideItem_02">
                            <div>
                                <div>1.2.1 Sub Menu</div>
                                <div>1.2.2 Sub Menu</div>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="button_desktop_01">2.0 Main Menu
                <div class="SlideItem_01">
                    <div class="button_desktop_02">2.1 Sub Menu
                        <div class="SlideItem_02">
                        <div>
                                <div>2.1.1 Sub Menu</div>
                                <div>2.1.2 Sub Menu</div>
                                <div>2.1.3 Sub Menu</div>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                    <div>2.2 Sub Menu</div>
                </div>
            </div>  

        </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
 .button_desktop_01{
 float: left;
 width: 20%;
 cursor: pointer;
 background: #5882FA;
 }

 .button_desktop_02 {
 position: relative;
 cursor: pointer;
 }

.SlideItem_01, .SlideItem_02 {
 display: none;
}

.SlideItem_02 {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 100%;
 width: 100%;
     background: #5882FA;
    }

 .button_desktop_01:hover, .button_desktop_02:hover,
 .button_desktop_01:active, .button_desktop_02:active,
 .button_desktop_01:link, .button_desktop_02:link,
 .button_desktop_01:visited, .button_desktop_02:visited {
 background: #CCCCCC;
 text-shadow: none;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button_desktop_01, .button_desktop_02").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).children(".SlideItem_01, .SlideItem_02").slideDown(500);
  });
  $(".button_desktop_01, .button_desktop_02").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).children(".SlideItem_01, .SlideItem_02").slideUp(500);
  });
});
```

The code above `slideUp/Down` some menus. All this works good so far.
However, now I want that each Sub Menu changes its colour once the user is hover it. I tried different ways but I could not make it work.

*For example the code above changes the colour of the entire menu and not just from the specific menu where the cursor is on. Besides, it does not cover anything that is part of `SlideItem_02`.*

What do I have to change in my CSS to make the hover effect work?

You can also find the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/by3d0kt9/6/

Comment: I see that, you have asked the same question twice in 2 days. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45649484/display-fadeitems-in-div-next-to-each-other AND https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45648868/structure-design-of-fadeitems-in-a-menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Nisarg0/by3d0kt9/7/

All you need to do is add a class, say `button` to every `div` that you want to respond to `hover`. Something like this:

```
<div class="SlideItem_02">
    <div>
        <div class="button">2.1.1 Sub Menu</div>
        <div class="button">2.1.2 Sub Menu</div>
        <div class="button">2.1.3 Sub Menu</div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

And then, add a CSS that changes the `div`'s style on hover:

```
.button:hover{
 background: #eee;
 text-shadow: none;
 color: red;
}
```

Of course, there could be more complicated ways of doing this, and they might work for you. But they are very likely to make a mess as you go on adding more navigation. Having a `button` class that handles all button related work seems the cleanest way to me in this case.

Comment: Hi Nisarg, thanks a lot for your help. I put it in my CSS and it looks almost the way I wanted it. The only thing I could not make work is the hover effect for the <div> with the class="button_desktop_01"  and  class="button_desktop_02" . I added the class="button" to them but the hover does not happen. Do you have any idea what I need to change in the code. Find an updated jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/by3d0kt9/8/

Comment: You can't write `class="button_desktop_01" class="button"`, because the other `class` attribute will be ignored. Instead you can combine the classes as follows, by keeping a space between them: `class="button_desktop_01 button"`.

Comment: Thanks for telling me this little trick. However, when I put it in my code the problem in my comment above still remains :-( See jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/by3d0kt9/10/

Comment: That's because your submenu buttons are under the same div that contains the text of main nav. You might need to refactor some of that code.

Comment: Hi Nisarg, thanks for the hint. I adjusted something and now it seems to work very good.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/by3d0kt9/11/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button_desktop_01, .button_desktop_02").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).children(".SlideItem_01, .SlideItem_02").slideDown(500);
  });
  $(".button_desktop_01, .button_desktop_02").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).children(".SlideItem_01, .SlideItem_02").slideUp(500);
  });
  
  $(".button_desktop_01 > div > div").not('.button_desktop_02').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
   $(this).addClass('visited_once');
  });
  
  $(".button_desktop_02 > div > div div").click(function(){
   $(this).addClass('visited_once');
  });
});
```

```css
 .button_desktop_01{
 float: left;
 width: 20%;
 cursor: pointer;
 background: #5882FA;
 }

 .button_desktop_02 {
 position: relative;
 cursor: pointer;
 }

.SlideItem_01, .SlideItem_02 {
 display: none;
}

.SlideItem_02 {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background: #5882FA;
}




 .button_desktop_01:hover, .button_desktop_02:hover,
 .button_desktop_01:active, .button_desktop_02:active,
 .button_desktop_01:link, .button_desktop_02:link,
 .button_desktop_01:visited, .button_desktop_02:visited {
 background: #CCCCCC;
 text-shadow: none;
}

.visited_once{
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navigation_desktop">

 <div class="button_desktop_01">1.0 Main Menu
  <div class="SlideItem_01">
   <div>1.1 Sub Menu</div>
   <div class="button_desktop_02">1.2 Sub Menu
    <div class="SlideItem_02">
     <div>
      <div>1.2.1 Sub Menu</div>
      <div>1.2.2 Sub Menu</div>
     </div> 
    </div>
   </div> 
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="button_desktop_01">2.0 Main Menu
  <div class="SlideItem_01">
   <div class="button_desktop_02">2.1 Sub Menu
    <div class="SlideItem_02">
      <div>
      <div>2.1.1 Sub Menu</div>
      <div>2.1.2 Sub Menu</div>
      <div>2.1.3 Sub Menu</div>
     </div> 
    </div>
   </div>  
   <div>2.2 Sub Menu</div>
  </div>
 </div> 
  
</div>
```

Updated code

**JS**

```
$(".button_desktop_01 > div > div").not('.button_desktop_02').click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
   $(this).addClass('visited_once');
});

$(".button_desktop_02 > div > div div").click(function(){
   $(this).addClass('visited_once');
});
```

**CSS**

```
.visited_once{
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

`Color` will change on `click` event.

Comment: Hi Shiladitya, thanks a lot for your code but it changes the colour of the entire menu and not just from the specific menu where the cursor is on and it does not cover anything that is part of SlideItem_02. Or is there something that I do wrong which causes the code not working?

Comment: I check the jsfiddle, everything is working. Something might be wrong while integrating the code..

Comment: It is strange becasue I tried it to run it here, on jsfiddle, on different browsers and cleared cookies and cache.

Comment: Can you share your jsfiddle? I checked it in incognito mode of chrome browser.